# Spring configure method not called

Tags: spring, spring-security

I tried to configure spring to allow encoded slashes in URL, but I cannot get the configuration to be applied

I've tried adding @EnableWebSecurity but it didn't seem to change anything. When I put breakpoints, the @Bean method is called but not configure().

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public HttpFirewall allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall() {
        DefaultHttpFirewall firewall = new DefaultHttpFirewall();
        firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedSlash(true);
        return firewall;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.httpFirewall(allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work using xml configuration. I added the following in my applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.firewall.DefaultHttpFirewall">
    <property name="allowUrlEncodedSlash" value="true"/>
</bean>
<security:http-firewall ref="allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall"/>
```